# I need help in passing a value from asp:linkbutton and string replacement using JQuery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have this LinkButton:

```asp
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" CssClass="lFilename" 
  ID="grdlinkFilename" Text='<%#Eval("FILEPATH")%>' 
  CommandArgument='<%#Eval("FILEPATH")%>'  OnCommand="grdlinkFilename_click" 
  data-id='<%#Eval("FILEPATH")%>'> </asp:LinkButton>
```

And in my external jquery file I did this:

```js
var result = $("#grdlinkFilename").attr("data-id");
result = result.replace(/D:\\/i, "http://ip/Vdrive/");
result = result.replace(/\\/g, "/");
```

What I want to do is to pass the value from the `<%#Eval("FILEPATH")%>` to my external jquery file. Suppose the value of `<%#Eval("FILEPATH")%`> is `d:\folder\img.jpg` in jquery.

I want to change from `d:\folder\img.jpg` to `d:\\folder\\img.jpg` (which is missing from my code for the jquery file).

Next again using jquery i'm going to change from `d:\\folder\\img.jpg` to `http://ip/Vdrive/folder/img.jpg`.

My concerns are:

1. Is my way off passing the value from my asp:linkbutton to external
   js file is correct including the way I call it? as in `var result =
   $("#grdlinkFilename").attr("data-id");`
2. If the way I pass the value from asp:linkbutton to external js file is correct, how can   I convert it's value to let say from "d:\folder\img.jpg" to "`d:\\folder\\img.jpg`"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In jQuery you can just call var result `$("#grdlinkFilename").data("id");`. No need to call it via .attr()
2. You can use C# to replace the backslashes if required:

`data-id='<%#((string)Eval("FILEPATH")).Replace(@"\", @"\\")%>'>`

Comment: Where can I put this code data-id='<%#((string)Eval("FILEPATH")).Replace(@"\", @"\\")%>'> ? Can I put in on the page load?

Comment: Put it inside your `<asp:LinkButton>` tag, like this: `<asp:LinkButton runat="server" CssClass="lFilename" 
  ID="grdlinkFilename" Text='<%#Eval("FILEPATH")%>' 
  CommandArgument='<%#Eval("FILEPATH")%>'  OnCommand="grdlinkFilename_click" 
  data-id='<%#((string)Eval("FILEPATH")).Replace(@"\", @"\\")%>'> </asp:LinkButton>`

Comment: I did it but nothing happens. It seems that the eval is not passing any value.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this in Jquery.

Before writing jquery like `$("#grdlinkFilename").attr("data-id");` you have to add the property called `ClienMode="static"` to the `<asp:LinkButton />`

Like

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ClienMode="static" CssClass="lFilename" ID="grdlinkFilename" Text='<%#Eval("FILEPATH")%>' CommandArgument='<%#Eval("FILEPATH")%>'  OnCommand="grdlinkFilename_click" data-id='<%#Eval("FILEPATH")%>'> </asp:LinkButton>
```

Then only the `<asp:LinkButton />` id will not changed after the compilation. The script will be executed. other wise run time the `server control ID  will be changed`. By View the Source you can see the changed id before adding this.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Is my way off passing the value from my asp:linkbutton to external js file is correct including the way I call it? as in var result =
>      $("#grdlinkFilename").attr("data-id");

Since you're using data- api, the ff. code will do:

```
var result = $("#grdlinkFilename").data("id");
```

> 1. If the way I pass the value from asp:linkbutton to external js file is
>      correct, how can I convert it's value to let say from
>      "d:\folder\img.jpg" to "d:\folder\img.jpg"?

```
result = result.replace(/\\/g, "\\\\");
```